# Windows don't show up in second monitor Debian ATI proprietary drivers

Tags: xorg, ati, fglrx, proprietary-drivers, xinerama

I've installed Debian 7.8 on my computer, then installed and attempted to configure the drivers. Everything went fine except for the fact that no windows show up on my second monitor at all. I enabled xinerama and enabled the displays on my display manager on Debian's side. The cursor and wallpaper is responsive but when I try to drag windows over they do not show up. Here is a picture of what I'm talking about;[image]

heres my xorg.conf;

```
#Section "ServerLayout"
#   Option "Xinerama" "on"
#   Option "Clone" "off"
#EndSection
#
#Section "ServerLayout"
#   Screen 0 "first-screen"
#   Screen 1 "second-screen RightOf "first-screen"
#EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
    Screen         "amdcccle-Screen[1]-1" LeftOf "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Option      "Xinerama" "on"
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option      "Xinerama" "on"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP6"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP7"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "1920 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP6" "0-DFP6"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP7" "0-DFP7"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "amdcccle-Device[1]-1"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP6" "0-DFP6"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen      1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Virtual   3840 1920
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amdcccle-Screen[1]-1"
    Device     "amdcccle-Device[1]-1"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: can you post the information of xrandr ?